# Weird pixelation effect on backdrop

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[Reupload with more information]

Hi!

I have a problem, you can see a weird pixelation effect on the backdrop of these renders. I don't know what causes them. I have a simple beveled backdrop with a beveled light setup. I use cycles and attached the blend file at the bottom.

Image:
[image: Cropped]

Pixelation effect highlighted, because it is hard to see in some light conditions:
[image: Effect highlighted]

Comment: maybe it's your denoiser?

Comment: What blender version you use? In Compositor is probably Denoiser node that is not recognised by 2.9x or 3.0 ... so it is Cycles X? BTW ... rendering without Compositor it is not pixelated ... so probably issue related to this node.

Comment: I'm using 2.92.0, but the weird thing is that I see this without the Denoiser node too, unlike you.

Comment: Hi :). Are you're by chance rendering with both CPU and GPU? That might sometimes cause this.

Comment: @JachymMichal Yes, actually I am. I will try with only GPU after this render. (brb in ~30 minutes)

Comment: @JachymMichal Yes, rendering with only GPU fixes the problem. (But sadly doubles render time on my potato pc.) Could you please write an answer instead of a comment so I can flag it as answered?

Comment: Hi :). I suggest to link your question with an older thread, just to keep the site organized. However, you can also report this behavior as a bug :).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!